# API for Stock Exchange and their Indexes data like Bloomberg

Tags: exchange

Actually I am looking for an API for stock exchange and their indexes data, And want to show data like this https://www.bloomberg.com/markets/stocks

[image: stock]

I searched various API provider, like WorldTradingData, AlphaVantage etc. But they only provide stock information, not exchange information,

If you know such API provider who can provide such type of data, please let me know, or any suggestion will be helpful for me,

Thanks

Comment: Hi, are you maybe conflating indexes and exchanges?

Comment: Indexes like the S&P 500 and the Dow 30 do not have affiliations with an exchange.  However, exchange composite indexes, as their names suggest, do.  For which type are you looking? Also, what data specifically (OHLC, volume, internals, etc)?

Comment: Actually I don't have in depth knowledge about stock market, one of my client just suggested the Bloomberg link, that what data he want to show on his website,
I need same data which bloomberg is showing, thanks

Comment: @BobJansen, No, as I read about stock market, Exchange and indexes are different thing, In an exchange there may be multiple indexes, so if is there any API provider who can provide data for exchange and index, please help me,

Comment: Please check out the linked question.

Comment: Which one? can you please share that question?

Comment: It's at the top of the page.

Comment: ok thanks man!!